# Looking for a program that can monitor and downscale images

Tags: windows-server-2012, image-processing, file-monitoring

I have a Windows 2012 webserver to which users upload images, and at that point i dont have any control over file size or images size. But, sometimes they do upload way too big images. These images only have to be shown in a 800x800 frame on a web page. So i'm thinking, is there a (preferably lightweight) piece of software which i can use to monitor these upload folders and scale down these images if needed? This would save me over 50% of disk space!

Comment: What server OS and version?  Imagemagick.org has command-line tools for Unix systems.

Comment: I have updated the question. Its a Windows 2012 server.

Comment: @cxw, there is a binary download for ImageMagick that can be used on Windows systems available from imagemagick.org at [Install from Binary Distribution](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/binary-releases.php): "ImageMagick runs on Windows 8 (x86 & x64), Windows 7 (x86 & x64), Windows Server 2012, Windows XP (x86) with Service Pack 3, Windows Vista (x86 & x64) with Service Pack 2, Windows Server 2003 (x86 & x64) with Service Pack 2 (verify MSXML6 is present), Windows Server 2003 R2 (x86 & x64), Windows Server 2008 (x86 & x64) with Service Pack 2, and Windows Server 2008 R2 (x64)."